# Grep and delete lines based on a pattern

Tags: unix, grep

I have a file which contains something like this,

`n-p: sd/is/b-t/km/lk
n-a: delete`

These two lines repeats throughout the file n-times,

I want to match the first line to contain /b-t/
and if the second line is delete then i want to delete the two lines and put the output into another file without changing first file.

so in short `if(first line contains /b-t/ and second line is delete) then delete both the lines`.

Can you guys please suggest a way of doing this as i am new to unix?

Thanks,
Sunil.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed ':loop; N; /.*b-t.*\n.*delete/{d; t loop;}; P;D;' yourfile > new_output
```

**Test:**

yourfile:

```
n-p: sd/is/b-t/km/lk 
n-a: delete
.. some ... text
n-p: sd/is/b-t/km/lk not match
.. some lines
.. some text
n-p: sd/is/b-t/km/lk 
n-a: delete
.. some ..
```

Run:

```
sat:~# sed ':loop; N; /b-t.*\n.*delete/{d;t loop;}; P;D;' yourfile 
.. some ... text
n-p: sd/is/b-t/km/lk not match
.. some lines
.. some text
.. some ..
sat:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is dirty:

```
awk -v RS="" '{gsub("n-p: \\S*/b-t/[^\n]*\n[^\n]*delete[^\n]*\n?","")}7' file
```

example:

```
kent$  cat f
n-p: sd/is/b-t/km/lk
n-a: delete
n-p: sd/is/bXt/km/lk
n-a: delete
n-p: sd/is/b-t/km/lk
n-a: foo
n-p: sd/are/b-t/km/lk
n-a: delete

kent$  awk -v RS="" '{gsub("n-p: \\S*/b-t/[^\n]*\n[^\n]*delete[^\n]*\n?","")}7' f
n-p: sd/is/bXt/km/lk
n-a: delete
n-p: sd/is/b-t/km/lk
n-a: foo
```